# c++ find the highest number of occurence in a string

Tags: c++, c++11, autocomplete

I'm developping a autocomplete program in c++.I have a dictionnary that i store in a class and now i have to find the number of occurence of each letter in a string (wich is a concatenation of all the string[x] i store in my dictionnary in a given x position).

I have thinked to do it with one of theses two solutions but i have no idea of what tools to use:

-store all theses 'tokens' in a std::vector and use a function who will find the highest number of occurence in it.

-do the same but with a std::string.

I have tried some wierd stuff with a std::map but i didn't manage to delete elements in it because i think i re instanciate elements in it when i was re-using it...

Comment: How are you going to implement the autocompletion? With a trie?

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do with some example code?

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: My dictionnary is store in a std::vector, to autocomplete the second character i think i thing i will store all the seconds character of all the line of my std::vector and concatenate it in a string. then i will search the most common char and i will display it. and so on and so on.

Comment: A [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with count seems more appropriate (so previous letters restrict future letters)

Comment: Are you talking about binary tree ?

Comment: No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I will check that. Thank you all !